# When I use the boat framework to start minecraft on Android, an error occurs problem

Tags: java, android, minecraft-forge

When I use the boat framework to start minecraft on Android, an error occurs.
The following is the error reported when the boat is running:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  Internal Error (assembler_aarch64.hpp:237), pid=14937, tid=0x0000007b51b54cb0
#  guarantee(val < (1U << nbits)) failed: Field too big for insn
#
# JRE version:  (8.0) (build )
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.71-b00 mixed mode linux-aarch64 compressed oops)
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#


---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )

Other Threads:

=>0xb400007b18b91000 (exited) JavaThread "Unknown thread" [_thread_in_vm, id=15485, stack(0x0000007b51953000,0x0000007b51b54cb0)]
```

The following is the error reported when Android Studio executes java through boat

```
E/Boat: #
    # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
    #
    #  Internal Error (assembler_aarch64.hpp:237), pid=28321, tid=0x0000007b4df8ecb0
    #  guarantee(val < (1U << nbits)) failed: Field too big for insn
    #
    # JRE version:  (8.0) (build )
    # Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.71-b00 mixed mode linux-aarch64 compressed oops)
    # Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
    #
E/Boat: # An error report file with more information is saved as:
    # /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.xiaodong.huachipokemon/files/huachipokemon/gamedir/hs_err_pid28321.log
A/libc: fdsan: attempted to close file descriptor 5, expected to be unowned, actually owned by FILE* 0x7bf0a144d8
```

Both APP and boat use `Android 11, api30, NDK: 21.3.6528147, BuildTools: 30.0.2, Android Gradle Plugin Version 4.1.1 Gradle Version 6.7.`
boat's github: `https://github.com/AOF-Dev/Boat`

Environment Variables:

```
JAVA_HOME=/data/user/0/com.xiaodong.huachipokemon/files/runtime/boat/j2re-image
PATH=/data/user/0/com.xiaodong.huachipokemon/files/runtime/boat/j2re-image/bin:/product/bin:/apex/com.android.runtime/bin:/apex/com.android.art/bin:/system_ext/bin:/system/bin:/system/xbin:/odm/bin:/vendor/bin:/vendor/xbin
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/data/user/0/com.xiaodong.huachipokemon/files/runtime/boat/j2re-image/lib/aarch64/server:/data/user/0/com.xiaodong.huachipokemon/files/runtime/boat/j2re-image/lib/aarch64/jli:/data/user/0/com.xiaodong.huachipokemon/files/runtime/boat/j2re-image/lib/aarch64:/system/lib64:/vendor/lib64:/vendor/lib64/hw
```

How to solve? I use Android Studio to compile a launcher to start minecraft. I use the boat framework to start. The parameters should be fine, but when I start the boat, an error is reported, an error related to java.

Answer (score 0):

I find the problem.Because the Boat use the lib is targetSdkVersion 22.
Add defaultConfig to App's build.grade {
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 22
versionCode 8
versionName '0.1'
} to start. But there is a new problem. After starting minecraft, half of the screen is black and half of it has a picture. what is the reason for this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybLWd.jpg)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).